# Average, per day. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, average

So, I have this file.txt, and I have to do the average temperature per day, the file.txt is a lot bigger, so there are a lot of days

```
data : 2021-05-01 16:52:13.074093
Temperature: 25.20 C
Pressure:    986.57 hPa 
Altitude:    224.50 
data : 2021-05-01 16:52:18.129364
Temperature: 25.20 C
Pressure:    986.55 hPa 
Altitude:    224.61
```

I made the average, but I don't know how to do it per day
this is the code so far

```
def temperature():
    print("The average temperature is:")
    total = 0.0
    c = 0
    with open("text.txt", 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if "Temperature" not in line: continue
            temp = line.split(" ")[1]
            total =total+ float(temp)
            c =c+ 1
    print(total / c)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def temperature():
    print("The average temperature is:")
    total = 0.0
    c = 0
    alltemp=[]
    with open(r"C:\VM\remove it.txt", 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if "Temperature" not in line: continue
            temp = line.split(" ")[1]
            total =total+ float(temp)
            c =c+ 1
            alltemp.append(total / c)
    print(total / c)
    return alltemp
```

alltemp will give you all the temperature in list

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it in pure Python:

```py
def temperature():
    temperatures = {}
    with open("text.txt", 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if "data" in line:
                day = line.split(" ")[2].strip()
            if "Temperature" in line:
                temp = float(line.split(" ")[1])
                if day in temperatures:
                    temperatures[day].append(temp)
                else:
                    temperatures[day] = [temp]

    for key,value in temperatures.items():
        print("Mean temperature on {} was {}".format(key, sum(value)/len(value)))
```

Idea: Supposing the date always precedes the temperature we can do it sequentially, first reading the date then the temperature.

When you encounter a "data" (date?) line, split (or regex) to keep only the date, and use this as a key to fill in a dictionary. The values are lists of temperatures, for that day. Once you are finished, iterate through your dictionary per day, and compute the mean (sum of the list of temperatures of the day, divided by length).

There are some hardcoded values in my answer. Your file is a bit "broken" (date line is called "data"? The colon is not consistent between lines, `data :`  versus `temperature:` ), so make sure the position in the `split` is correct. Use regular expressions if you can't guarantee it's consistent across the file.

Answer (score 0):

Since the date and temperature are on different lines, your code needs to remember the current (last seen) day. Then you can group the temperatures per day, for example in a dictionary:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

temp_per_day = defaultdict(list)
current_day = None
total = count = 0

for line in f:
    if line[:4] == 'data':
        current_day = line.split()[2]
    elif 'Temperature' in line:
        temp = float(line.split()[1])
        total += temp
        count += 1
        temp_per_day[current_day].append(temp)
```

Then you can iterate over the temperature values for each day and compute the average:

```py
for day, temps in temp_per_day.items():
    avg_temp = sum(temps) / len(temps)
    print(f'average temperature on {day} is {avg_temp:.2f}')
```